# Login website by using openssl in C

Tags: c, facebook, sockets, https, openssl

I wrote a program in C what will get the code html of my facebook's homepage.
I use the SSL library for https protocol.
I created a socket port 443, then send and receive http message through this port.
As I know, I have to send 3 request: first one to get facebook login page and some cookie, the 2nd to post the login infomation and the 3rd to get the homepage.
These are my three requests:

```
char *request0 = "GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.facebook.com\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n";//first request for login form & cookie
char *request1_fm = "POST /login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110 HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.facebook.com\nCookie: %s\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nContent-Length: %d\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n%s"; //second for post login
char *request2_fm = "GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.facebook.com\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\nCookie: %s\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n";//third for facebook's homepage
```

request1 and request2 will be completed follow their format above: request1_fm, request2_fm. 
And these are my functions to send and receive http messages:

```
void send_request(SSL *ssl, char *req, BIO *outbio) {
  int bytes;
  int sent = 0;
  int total = strlen(req);
  do {
    bytes = SSL_write(ssl, req + sent, total - sent);
    if (bytes < 0) {
      BIO_printf(outbio, "\nError writing...\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (bytes == 0) break;
    sent += bytes;
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Sent... %d bytes\n", sent);
 } while (bytes > 0);
 BIO_printf(outbio, "Send DONE!\n");
}

char *receive_response(SSL *ssl, BIO *outbio) {
  int bytes;
  int received = 0;
  char *response;
  char buf[4096];
  memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
  do {
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (bytes < 0) {
        BIO_printf(outbio, "\nError reading...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (bytes == 0) break;
    received += bytes;
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Received...%d bytes", received);
    strncat(response, buf, bytes);
  } while (bytes > 0);
  BIO_printf(outbio, "Received DONE\n");
  return response;
}
```

It didn't work. I can't send and receive anything. I don't know where I went wrong. Help me please.

Comment: Here is where you went wrong: _“I wrote a program in C what will get the code html of my facebook's homepage”_ – scraping Facebook or using any kind of automated tools to login is against their ToS. If you want to interact with Facebook – **use. their. API.**

Comment: :( This is my homework. I am asked to do by this way, and then handling the html code I've got.

Comment: Then tell your teacher that they should please pay more attention to the ToS of the sites they pick as "targets" next time.

Comment: I used Graph API instead. Thank you.